# sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, azure-ad-msal

I am following this microsoft doc in order to obtain an access token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-acquire-token?tabs=java

however I am getting this casting error when I try to run my code:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

Here is my code:

```
private static String GetToken() throws Exception {
  IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret);
        ConfidentialClientApplication cca =
                ConfidentialClientApplication
                        .builder(clientId, credential)
                        .authority(authority)
                        .build();

        // Client credential requests will by default try to look for a valid token in the
        // in-memory token cache. If found, it will return this token. If a token is not found, or the
        // token is not valid, it will fall back to acquiring a token from the AAD service. Although
        // not recommended unless there is a reason for doing so, you can skip the cache lookup
        // by using .skipCache(true) in ClientCredentialParameters.
        ClientCredentialParameters parameters =
                ClientCredentialParameters
                        .builder(SCOPE)
                        .build();

        return cca.acquireToken(parameters).join().accessToken();


}
```

I tried to look online but it seems like the solutions are not MSAL4J specific

Comment: Can you post your import statements too? Does it match https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/dev/src/samples/confidential-client/ClientCredentialGrant.java

Comment: Yes, it matches it exactly